# I want a extra column while querying using SELECT statement. the column value should look like this,

Tags: mysql, sql, select

| name | class | marks | new_column## | Heading ## |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| jim | 1 | 50 | 1 |  |
| jim | 2 | 50 | 1 |  |
| jim | 3 | 40 | 1 |  |
| tom | 4 | 30 | 2 |  |
| tom | 3 | 70 | 2 |  |
| tom | 2 | 80 | 2 |  |
| tom | 1 | 70 | 2 |  |
| tom | 5 | 80 | 2 |  |

The name column changes every time I query but a similar name will come each time(like 5 Herry, 6 Lucy).

So I want a new_column where first similar names are assigned 1 and next similar names will be assigned 2 and so on.

Comment: I've gone ahead and removed the tag spam here; please only tag the RDBMS you are *really* using. Tagging multiple conflicting technologies makes your question unclear and thus *harder* to answer. It is also unlikely to get your question "more views" and likely to have the opposite effect, where only users who know *all* the RDBMS you have (mis)tagged will entertain the question; that is often a very small portion of the user base. Tag spam is far more likely to result in your question receiving downvotes and/or being closed as unclear. Please [edit] your question to retag the correct RDBMS.

Comment: Are you asking for new column to be assigned a value based on ascending order of name? and why show heading# column when it does not appear to be pertinent to the question.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) I have rolled back your edit to remove the text and add an image, as it is *not* helpful.

Comment: [[tag:rdbms]] doesn't tell us anything... You need to tag the RDBMS you are using, *not* tag RDBMS.

Comment: sorry i didn't get your point -- @Larnu

Comment: You *spammed* the tags with multiple RDBMS products when you created your question, with tags like [[tag:mysql]], [[tag:sql-server]], [[tag:postgresql]], and [[tag:sqlite]]; all of those are **completely** different products. It's like telling someone you're using "MacOS Windows Ubuntu FreeBDS" when asked what Operating system you are using. What RDBMS are you *really* using?

Comment: I use MySQL RDBMS. i tagged all of them because the concept might be same.--@Larnu

Comment: Every (R)DBMS uses a different dialect of SQL, @user591974 . See my original comment on why spamming the tags, when they aren't related to the product you are using, is not helpful and is confusing.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for the `dense_rank` window function:

```sql
SELECT   *, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY name) AS new_column
FROM     mytable
ORDER BY name
```

Comment: You probably mean `DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY name)`,not `RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY name)`.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner arg, yes. Good catch on both accounts.